# XCode - See console output after app exit, when running multiple app instances

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, exit, nslog

When I run two apps from XCode debugger, I can see their own NSLog into the console.
But when one app exist with an `exit` call, it is killed and I can't see the console log anymore. How may I do to be able to see it.

In other words, i'm debugging the app, and when something bad happens, I have put a message in the log followed by an exit. I would want to see the place where that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your `exit` call with a

```
raise(SIGINT);
```

the execution of the program will be paused if you're running with a debugger attached. If you're running without a debugger (i.e. in production), the app will be killed.

Answer (score 2):

Select what is called the "Log Navigator" and select the debug session, see image

[image]